# Why doesn't error.tsx work in with NextJS app directory, even with "use client"?

Tags: next.js

**Background:**

I'm using NextJS 13.4 and the new app directory.

I have a folder called `products` inside of the `app` folder.

In the `products` folder I have the file `page.tsx`, which loads fine.

But when I try to add the file `error.tsx` I get errors.

The content of `error.tsx`, following the official docs:

```
"use client";

export default function Error({ error, reset }: { error: Error, reset: () => void }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => reset()}>Try again</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

**Current behaviour:**

I get the error `"./app/products/error.tsx must be a Client Component. Add the "use client" directive the top of the file to resolve this issue."` even though I have it at the top of the file

**Expected behavior:**

That the page loads fine and that the error component shows when an error occurs

Why does it complain about "use client" when I do have it at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be coming from the cached pages. Delete the .next folder then, run "npm run dev"

Comment: Deleting the .next folder and rerunning had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to create a new page.tsx and error.tsx in a new folder. Using the information you provided, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Your component works just fine when testing. If you want some more help debugging this, could you provide your page.tsx, related layout.tsx file and your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

In your Pages.tsx if you have

```
export dynamicParams = false
```

then it always use the src level or page level not-found or error component

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).